# Tabbing through input fields with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, keypress, tabindex

i'm dealing with a nice problem:

i've got a jqueryUI dialog, which contains from 3 to 8  fields: on "TAB" keypress, i want the focus to pass through those fields, one after the other following the order i previously set to tabindex html attribute.

I've read online that tabindex attribute isn't treated by the same way from browsers.. and i've been trying it on my own skin.

So.. the question is: is there a way to implement this circular behaviour after TAB key pression?

NB: I can't use third-party plugins..

Here the piece of code that i'm working on:

```
//... here i set the right values of tabindex to my input fields and then
$.each($array, function (index, elem) {

        var el = elem;

        $(el).on('focus', function (e) {
            $(window).keyup(function (e) {
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if (code == 9) {
                    var nextIndex = $(el).attr('tabindex') + 1;

                    if (!($('.testPopup').find('input[tabindex=' + nextIndex + ']').length > 0)) {
                        nextIndex = 1;
                    }

                    //using timeout - leaves the event following its default behaviour and completing it
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.testPopup').find('input[tabindex=' + nextIndex + ']').focus();
                    }, 1);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**UPDATE**

I've been able to improve my previous solution, here's the code:

```
$(el).on('focus', function (e) {
            $(el).off('keydown').on('keydown', function (e) {

                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if (code == 9) {

                    var nextIndex = $(el).attr('tabindex') + 1;

                    if (!($('.testPopup').find('input[tabindex=' + nextIndex + ']').length > 0)) {
                        nextIndex = 1;
                    }

                    //using timeout - leaves the event following its default behaviour and completing it
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        //Here is the trick which would make my solution working,
                        //but it wouldn't be a flexible reusable solution
                        //$(el).datepicker("hide");
                        $('.testPopup').find('input[tabindex=' + nextIndex + ']').focus();
                    }, 1);

                    //e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
```

Currently the problem is as follow: tabbing through the dialog will focus the right next input-field, but one of these input-fields is a jQueryUI datepicker which is not gonna close itself. If you look at the code i updated, you'll see a commented line `$(el).datepicker("hide");` which would make the datepicker close.. but, come on.. it the worst solution ever..

I know the fault is of that `e.stopPropagation()`, but.. how can I make it work? Any suggestion??

Comment: edited the question with a piece of code

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've posted? Does it have any errors?

Comment: No, everything ok.. It simply doesn't work.. all the elements seem to be focused one after the other when pressing TAB key on one of them.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the tabindex property of the dom(here input element).

Eg :
`<input type="text"  placeholder="User Name" id="username" name="username" value="This is a test" onkeydown="checkEvent(event);" tabindex='1' />`

Comment: tabindex attribute won't work. I already tried it and it didn't work.. And also if it would work, i couldn't use it because of others HTML elements tabbable which are outside the current dialog.

Comment: Then you can have your own function that will set the order of the tab based on the selector (id,class).Hope this will be helpful.Can you pls up vote to remove my negative reputation only if you find this comment useful.

Comment: If you read the code i wrote in my question's post, you'd see i already did what you are suggesting. Thanks for you try, see ya.